# How to use a list of model names and variables for computing a table with its predictions?

Tags: r, regression

I am currently doing regression analysis on a dataset of mine, and thought that in order to compare different regression models, I could use a table. I would like the table to have the names of the model in the first column, and the predicted values on 1 test point on in the second column.

What I have done now is systematically named these models as follows:

```r
library(caret)
model.lm <- train(formula, data=train, method='lm',...)
model.glmnet<- train(formula, data=train, method='glmnet',...)
...
Modelnames <- c('lm', 'glmnet',...)
results <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=n, ncol=2)), c('Model', 'Prediction'))
results$Model <- Modelnames
results$Prediction <- predict(model. , test) (?)
```

and so on for several models.

Now, I was wondering if there is any way I could use `Modelnames` in order to quickly do predictions per model, rather than having to type `predict()` for each model by hand. Is there some way to convert the `Modelnames` to the `model.` format? Ideally it would be a oneliner, like

```
results$Prediction <- predict(model.results[,1], test)
```

or something of the sort. It's probably wrong, but I hope you get the gist of what I meant with that line.

Comment: `modelList <- lapply(Modelnames, function(mod) train(formula, data=train, method=mod,...)); predictions <- sapply(modelList, predict, newdata = data.frame(...))`

Comment: @heck1 Thank you! I see, I thought for this particular problem it was not a high priority to provide the dataset. I will keep this in mind for next time.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I removed my comment because "my" method focuses on more "advanced" models and didn't really think of lm and glm implementations when I wrote it. :). I'll readd it for future reference. One can use **Self Promotion** [manymodelr::multi_model_1](https://www.github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr). This does not support `lm` and `glm` since it needs a metric.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much! I had not thought about writing a particular function for it. It saves a lot of time, excellent.

Comment: @Roland Sorry to bother you again, but is there a way to log the procedure of lapply here? I would like it to print something like 'mod done' after every iteration. However, by adding '; print(paste(mod, 'done'))' in the function, the use of modelList would be gone.

Comment: Assign the return value of train in the anonymous function to a temporary variable, create your message (using the function message instead of print is better practice) and let the function return the temp var.

Comment: @Roland I got it to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with multiple models I prefer to work with a dataframe with list columns

example:

```
require(caret)
require(tidyverse)

dt <- data.frame(method = c('lm', 'glmnet')) %>%
  mutate(model = map(method, ~ train(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
                                     data = iris, 
                                     method = .x))) %>%
  mutate(predicted = map(model, predict))

dt %>% select(method,predicted) %>%
  unnest()
```

The last line gives all predicted values of both models in a dataframe. This can easily be altered to give the value of only one prediction.